# How can i extract only text in scrapy selector in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code

```
   site = hxs.select("//h1[@class='state']")
   log.msg(str(site[0].extract()),level=log.ERROR)
```

The ouput is

```
 [scrapy] ERROR: <h1 class="state"><strong>
            1</strong>
            <span> job containing <strong>php</strong> in <strong>region</strong> paying  <strong>$30-40k per year</strong></span>
                </h1>
```

Is it possible to only get the text without any html tags

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
//h1[@class='state']
```

in your above xpath you are selecting `h1` tag that has `class` attribute `state`

so that's why it's selecting everything that comes in `h1 element`

if you just want to select text of `h1` tag all you have to do is

```
//h1[@class='state']/text()
```

if you want to select text of `h1` tag as well as its children tags, you have to use

```
//h1[@class='state']//text()
```

so the difference is `/text()` for specific tag text and `//text()` for text of specific tag as well as its children tags

below mentioned code works for you

```
site = ''.join(hxs.select("//h1[@class='state']/text()").extract()).strip()
```

Comment: Excellent explanation of the difference of `/text()` and `//text()`

Comment: `xpath` should never be underestimated

Answer (score 3):

I haven't got a scrapy instance running so I couldn't test this; but you could try to use `text()` within your search expression.

For example:

```
site = hxs.select("//h1[@class='state']/text()")
```

(got it from the [`tutorial`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.9/intro/tutorial.html))

Answer (score 3):

You can use BeautifulSoup `get_text()` feature.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<td><a href="http://www.fakewebsite.com">Please can you strip me?</a>
<br/><a href="http://www.fakewebsite.com">I am waiting....</a>
</td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

print(soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to strip html tags, here is an example:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
''.join(BeautifulSoup(str(site[0].extract())).findAll(text=True))
```

You can then strip all the additional whitespaces, new lines etc.

if you don't want to use additional modules, you can try simple regex:

```
# replace html tags with ' '
text = re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', ' ', str(site[0].extract()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html2text`

```
import html2text
converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
print converter.handle("<div>Please!!!<span>remove me</span></div>")
```