# How can I get the text clean with scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying the following command on scrapy shell which returns this result:

```
In [49]: response.css('h4.team-meta__name')[1].extract()                                                                                                                 
Out[49]:h4 class="team-meta__name" style="color: #6495ED">   <strong>Ajax</strong></h4
```

The thing is, I want to extract only the word "Ajax" that is is between `<strong>` tags.

Comment: Not sure about scrapy, but with `BeautifulSoup` you would add `.text()` to extract the text :)

Comment: and where should i add it ? :)

Comment: See here for examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489473/how-can-i-extract-only-text-in-scrapy-selector-in-python

Comment: does not help, since i'm not using BS, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<strong>` tag to your selector

```
response.css('h4.team-meta__name strong::text')[1].extract()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir :) it works! can you explain why there is no "." between name and strong ?

Comment: We use `.` in css selectors when we need to select elements by `class` attribute. In this case `strong` is tag name. css selector looks for text inside `strong` tag inside `h4` tag with `team-meta__name` class

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is It possible to when we extract the data in to a csv file, we save It into a table? If so can you give me an example?